# Store WINAPI Functionpointer in struct

Tags: c, winapi, struct

I have the following problem: I have to build a DLL with some Header-Files from a supplier. There are some typedefs in those headerfiles which store WINAPI-Functionpointers.

Example:

```
typedef struct {
    int(WINAPI *myFunc)(int, int);
}
```

However, VS2015 always underlines the star ("*") saying it expected an ")".
I cant change the functions stored in those pointers so I have to fix this.

Anyone knows a solution for this?

Comment: but compiler ok here ? except [`C4094`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7y0f9tby.aspx) warning, because you have unnamed struct. if yes - no any problems

Comment: do you have `windows.h` included before these declarations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the WINAPI-Macro is defined in `Windows.h`, I just forgot to include it.

Result: Including the -Header seems to fix this problem.

Comment: This doesn't really qualify as an answer...

Comment: @FelixPalmen it is a self answer. So I guess it is fine. Other option would be to delete the question all together. But rather it remain, because it is a common error many programmers do.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya I think it should *at least* explain that `WINAPI` is a macro, defined in `windows.h`. But then, it's a trivial error and should be closed anyway for *cannot be reproduced any more*

Comment: @FelixPalmen Okay, closing the question seems apt. Please vote to close it.